# What is the meaning of semicolon(;) in (; 'echo "$@" ')?

Tags: bash, echo

*Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible*,<sup>[[1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linux_Command_Line_and_Shell_Scripting_B/ywUaBgAAQBAJ)]</sup> page 462, gives the below example of passing an array into a function by passing its individual values as function parameters and reassembling them into an array inside the function:

> ```
> $ cat test10
> #!/bin/bash
> # array variable to function test
>
> function testit {
>    local newarray
>    newarray=(;'echo "$@"')
>    echo "The new array value is: ${newarray[*]}"
> }
>
> myarray=(1 2 3 4 5)
> echo "The original array is ${myarray[*]}"
> testit ${myarray[*]}
> $
> $ ./test10
> The original array is 1 2 3 4 5
> The new array value is: 1 2 3 4 5
> $
> ```

What does the `;` mean in the `newarray=(;'echo "$@"')` bit?
And are the single quotation marks required?

Comment: As far as I know, it is a syntax error. :-)

Comment: Please type the exact code from the book. (It wouldn't hurt to identify the book and page number.) In particular, spaces are not allowed around the `=` when you set a variable. `foo=bar` sets `$foo` to `"bar"`. `foo = bar` tries to invoke a command called `foo` with arguments `"="` and `"bar"`. But yes, even with the spaces removed a semicolon in that place would be a syntax error. But we can't tell whether it's an error in the book or a transcription error on your part.

Comment: I agree with the other comments above. Also, No good with single quotes. You may have mistaken single quotes as back-quotes `(\`)` which provide the shell feature *command-substition* (read elsewhere about this) . That would only be useful if you are passing in a command that will generate output that should be assigned to the array in your script. Possible, but also edit your Q to show the sample usage provided in the book for this function. More tyically, it would just be a lists of words to be used as the array values. Good luck.

Comment: I am sorry for the typo errors. I brought if from the book called 'Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible', page 462.

The whole script is

$cat test10
#!/bin/bash

function testit {
    local newarray
    newarray=(;`echo "$@"`)
    echo "The new array value is: ${newarray[*]}"
}

myarray=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo "The original array is ${myarray[*]}"
testit ${myarray[*]}

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons are used to run multiple commands in one string one after another without piping them.

```
ls; echo ok; exit
```

But this won't work from a var or an array.

```
a="ls; echo ok"
$ $a

Command 'ls;' not found, did you mean:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid syntax; the book seems to have a copy-paste error or something.

In order for the example to do what the text says it's trying to do, this:

```
   newarray=(;'echo "$@"')
```

should be just this:

```
   newarray=("$@")
```

(no `;`, no `'`, no `echo`).

Additionally, this:

```
testit ${myarray[*]}
```

should be this:

```
testit "${myarray[@]}"
```

(`"`, `@` instead of `*`) to avoid misbehaving when an array element contains whitespace or special characters. (More generally, from the few pages I've looked at, this book doesn't seem to demonstrate robust code; so even for the examples that will work if you try them on simple inputs, I don't recommend putting too much trust in them.)